# Duplicate R.java file getting generated while Proguard obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

When i run ant build of my config.xml file , i get compiler error saying :

Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

E:\workspace\USSDHandlingDemo\src\com\et\ussdhandling\R.java:10:

duplicate class: com.et.ussdhandling.R

public final class R

2 errors

please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it..!

I had to delete the R.java file from the explorer (outside of eclipse)
first and then do the ant build.

This may help someone.